# clang-format lambda : brace on next line but preserve everything before brace on current line

Tags: c++, clang-format

In the clang-format page:

[https://clang.llvm.org/docs/ClangFormatStyleOptions.html#:~:text=bool%20BeforeLambdaBody%20Wrap%20lambda%20block](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/ClangFormatStyleOptions.html#:%7E:text=bool%20BeforeLambdaBody%20Wrap%20lambda%20block)

Appears just two ways of aling the lambdas, based on `BeforeLambdaBody` value:

```
true:
connect(
  []()
  {
    foo();
    bar();
  });

false:
connect([]() {
  foo();
  bar();
});
```

Anybody knows a way to achieve this kind of aligment, pushing to the new line ONLY the brace:

```
connect([]()
{
  foo();
  bar();
});
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, this is not possible with the [latest](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/index.html) `clang-format`.

You can open an issue in the [clang-format Github repository](https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/labels/clang-format).